# for loop optimization for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Based on the row value of my original dataframe I need to change another dataframe row value. This code works but execution time is very high.

I tried multiple form of for loop and functions (iterrows, iteritems, apply) but it didn't help.

Here's my code:

```
%%timeit
for value in tqdm(range(len(data['DPS_NUM']))):
    for col_nm in ts_col:
        temp = data[col_nm][value]
        if temp != '':
            data2[temp][value] = 1
```

Original dataframe:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
123  foo  bar  zoo
456  bar  foo
789  zoo  zoo
```

Expected dataframe:

```
col1 foo bar zoo
123   1   1   1
456   1   1   1
789           1
```

My code works but it's slow, I need to optimize it.

Comment: can you explain the logic a little

Comment: no idea how you come from your original to your excpected df . it looks as if you are turning the 1 / empty fields by 90 degrees and put other columnheaders on them .. I dont get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and aggregate `max` per columns:

```
#if first column is index
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix ='', prefix_sep='').max(axis=1, level=0)
print (df)
      bar  foo  zoo
col1               
123     1    1    1
456     1    1    0
789     0    0    1


#if first column is not index
#df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('col1'), prefix ='', prefix_sep='').max(axis=1, level=0)
```

Comment: did you understand how he comes from orignal to expected? yours is not his expected ... (but yours made sense until you edited it - his does not)

Comment: hi can you please explain why we need to call .max() func on this

Comment: @rahuldesai - sure, there is possible problem duplicated columns, if test `print (pd.get_dummies(df, prefix ='', prefix_sep=''))` get multiple `bar`, `zoo` and `foo` columns. And if need indicator columns need `max` per columns - it return only `1` or `0` - it aggregate by columns names and call function max.